# Union of two arrays

Tags: c#, java, algorithm

Given two arrays

```
int arr1[n]
int arr2[m]
```

where n > m

Need to write a union of two arrays into one.

For example, if the input arrays are:

```
   int arr1[] = {1, 3, 4, 5, 7}
   int arr2[] = {2, 3, 5, 6}
```

Then program should create new array Union as `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`

Implementation can be in C# or Java.

In order to solve it first of all need to to sort the arrays using Merge Sort
and then do the union

I looked in the net but did not find the elegant way . Every code that I looked
was full of IF's.

Please advice what is the most quick and elegant way to do it

Comment: What is the implementation language?

Comment: What are your assumptions? Are you thinking of the arrays as sets or are repetitions allowed? Must the result be sorted?

Comment: There is nothing inherently inelegant with `if` statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that merging the two lists as is done in [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is the most efficient thing to do. This assumes that the two lists are already sorted, as in your example. Here is an example of how to implement merge:

```
function merge(left,right)
    var list result
    while length(left) > 0 or length(right) > 0
        if length(left) > 0 and length(right) > 0
            if first(left) ≤ first(right)
                append first(left) to result
                left = rest(left)
            else
                append first(right) to result
                right = rest(right)
        else if length(left) > 0
            append first(left) to result
            left = rest(left)
        else if length(right) > 0
            append first(right) to result
            right = rest(right)
    end while
    return result
```

From here, simply do not include repeats in the final output.

Answer (score 2):

If its an elegant MergeSort you are looking then nothing is more elegant than a recursive function :-)

Here it is :

This is a divide and conquer strategy. We basically divide the array into smaller arrays , sort the smaller arrays and merge them back.

```
public static void mergesort(int a[],int left, int right){
    /*
    *  Time : O(n log n)
    *  Space : O(n)
    */
    int b[] = new int[right -left+1];
    domergesort(a,left,right,b);
}

public static void domergesort(int a[],int left,int right, int b[]){

    if(left < right){
        int mid = (left+right)/2;
        domergesort(a,left,mid,b);
        domergesort(a,mid+1,right,b);
        merge(a,left,mid,a,mid+1,right,b);
        for(int k=left;k<=right;k++)
            a[k] = b[k-left];
    }
}
```

Not many ifs too ..

Source : My Blog (http://cloudingitup.blogspot.com/p/reading-guide-arrays.html)

To merge them together as a Union :

```
public static void merge( int a[], int al, int ar, int b[], int bl, int br, int c[]){
    // al : a's left index ar : a's right index c: merged array
    int i= al;
    int j = bl;
    int k=0;
    int prev = c[0]; 

    while ( i<= ar && j <= br){
        if (a[i] <= b[j])
          if (prev != a[i]) // Too keep the union distinct
              c[k++] = a[i++];
          else
             i++;
        else
            if (prev != b[j]) // Too keep the union distinct
                c[k++] = b[j++];
            else
                j++;

        prev = c[k-1];

    }

    while (i <= ar)
     {
     if (prev != a[i])
        c[k++] = a[i++];
      else
         i++;

       prev = c[k-1];
      }


    while (j <= br)
     {
     if (prev != b[j])
        c[k++] = b[j++];
      else
         j++;
       prev = c[k-1];
      }

}
```

A driver code to illustrate the code :

```
int arr1[] = {1,1, 3, 4,4,4,5, 7};
int arr2[] = {2, 3, 5, 6,6,8};
int c[] = new int[8];

merge(arr1,0,7,arr2,0,5,c);

for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
System.out.print(c[i]);
```

Output: 12345678

Comment: well this one has some ifs :-O

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void printUnion(int ar1[],int ar2[]) {
        int m = ar1.length;
        int n = ar2.length;
        int i=0,j=0;

        while(i<m && j<n) {
            if( ar1[i] <ar2[j]) {
                System.out.println(ar1[i]);
                i++;
            }else if(ar1[i] > ar2[j]) {
                System.out.println(ar2[j]);
                j++;
            }else {
                System.out.println(ar1[i]);
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        while(i < m)
               System.out.println(ar1[i++]);
        while(j < n)
               System.out.println(ar2[j++]);
}
```

Same code will work for intersection with minimal changes....

Answer (score 0):

In interviews, they usually want to see you solve the problem, rather than using library calls (e.g. `arr1.union(arr2)` probably wouldn't cut it.)

This is off the top of my head, but something like this should work, and I think is O(n^2).  It assumes both arrays are sorted.

union.rb

```
arr1 = [0,2,4,9,11,12,13]
arr2 = [3,4,7,9,10,11]

def union(n, m)
  if n.last > m.last
    arr1 = n; arr2 = m
  else
    arr1 = m; arr2 = n
  end

  union_array = []
  j = 0
  arr1.each do |x|
    while j < arr2.length && arr2[j] < x
      if arr2[j] < x
        union_array << arr2[j] unless arr2[j] == union_array.last
        j += 1
      end
    end
    union_array << x
  end
  union_array
end

puts union(arr1, arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

this method should work fairly well, and it will decide which array is bigger so there doesn't need to necessarily be a defined order.

Java:

```
public static <T> T[] combine(T[] a1, T[] a2)
{
    return combine(a1, a2, a1.length + a2.length);
}
public static <T> T[] combine(T[] a1, T[] a2, int maxlength)
{
    T[] front = null;
    T[] back = null;
    if(a1.length >= a2.length)
    {
        front = a1;
        back = a2;
    }
    else
    {
        front = a2;
        back = a1;
    }
    int len = front.length + back.length;
    if(len > maxlength)
    {
        len = maxlength;
    }
    int n = 0;
    T[] result = Arrays.copyOf(front, len);
    int c = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < front.length;i++)
    {
        if(i < front.length && c < result.length)
        {
            result[c] = front[i];
            c++;
        }
        if(i < back.length && c < result.length)
        {
            result[c] = back[i];
            c++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

this is obviously not the most efficient method, but it does completely work. It also includes a capping, if you want to merge them, but only get the first, let's way 5 items, then you can add a parameter of 5 to the method.

You can actually get rid of a lot of waste, there's a lot of messy stuff in here, I'm away from my IDE so it's off my head, I may have stuff that's not needed.